# Sorting a String using java collections

Tags: java, sorting

I am attaching  following code and i want to sort this as

```
 class sort{
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {String a ="this is a kiran";  
    StringTokenizer st =new StringTokenizer(a);  
    List f=new ArrayList();  
    f.add(st);  
    Collections.sort(f);  
    System.out.println("after sortting "+f);  
    }
 }
```

I want output as:

```
a
is 
kiran 
this
```

But i am getting an exception as:-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.StringTokenizer cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparableat java.util.Collections.sort(UnknownSource)atcom.sort.main(Sort.java:18)

Comment: why not use string.split("\\s+") instead of String tokenizer?

Comment: You can't just add the StringTokenizer to your list.  Use the StringTokenizer to iterate through the tokens.

Comment: The StringTokenizer class does not implement the Comparable interface. _"All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list)."_

Comment: @ZouZou - excellent point...

Answer (score 4):

Change your code. There are some mistakes you need to correct.

```
    String a ="this is a kiran";
    StringTokenizer st =new StringTokenizer(a);
    List<String> f=new ArrayList<>(); // use String type list
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){ // add all tokens by iterating st
        f.add(st.nextToken()); // add tokens to list
    }
    Collections.sort(f);
    System.out.println("after sorting "+f);
```

Out put:

```
   after sorting [a, is, kiran, this]
```

Now you are getting sorted list

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
f.add(st);
```

You are adding `StringTokenizer` to the list, instead of adding the individual tokens. Changing the code to use generics would have helped: if you declare your `List` as `List<String>`, the code wouldn't compile, pointing you in the right direction:

```
List<String> f=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Add a `while` loop to collect tokens from `st`, and add them to `f` one by one.

P.S. Since this is almost certainly a learning exercise, I am not going to spoil the fun for you by completing your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `hasMoreElements()` and `nextElement()`

```
class sort{
   public static void main(String args[])  {
       String a ="this is a kiran";
        StringTokenizer st =new StringTokenizer(a);
        ArrayList<String> f=new ArrayList<String>(); // use String type list
        while (st.hasMoreElements()){ // add all by iterating st
        f.add((String) st.nextElement()); // add tokens to list
    }
    Collections.sort(f);
    System.out.println("after sorting "+f);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using String.split() to split your string.
Class names should be nouns,
method names should be verbs or verb phrases,
and you should use generics.

```
public static void main(String[] arguments)
{
    String input = "this is hootberry sause";  
    String[] inputArray;
    List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();

    inputArray = input.split(" ");
    Collections.addAll(inputList, inputArray);
    Collections.sort(inputList);

    System.out.println("Before sort: " + input);
    System.out.println("After sort: " + inputList);
}
```